# Cycle over windows of the same application with keyboard shortcut - GNOME 3

Tags: debian, gnome, window

Using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> for cycling over the opened windows doesn't cycle over the different windows of the same application.

For example, I've got some terminals opened, and pressing the key <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>
groups the windows so I cannot cycle between recent windows of the same application easily. Then I have to use the mouse to do so.

[image]

Is there any way to change this so I can change rapidly over windows of the same application?

Comment: Ctrl + \` (a.k.a. Ctrl+Shift+~)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From gnome tweaks select extensions, there's an "Alternatetab" extension which I guess is pre-installed but is off. Switch it to on.